# Function in Field Calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

One of the columns in my attribute table is called "table_ot".
Some of the features in that column start with a letter. Example: table_ot = G 190
I want to delete all the letters at the start of the feature's value and end up with something like this:
table_ot = 190

Can you please write down the correct code for the field calculator? I tried some things that don't run.

Comment: Are your numbers all of the same length, e.g. all of them three digits? Or are the letters all the same? Also, if you posted some of your trials, that could be helpful.

Comment: I tried something like this: replace ( "table_ot" , 'G ' , '' )

Answer (score 1):

if everything after the first letter is a digit, you can use

> regexp_substr("table_ot",'(\\d+)')

Comment: Does this also work, if there is no beginning letter?

Comment: yes, this expression extract every digit in a value.  If there is no letter in it, it just returns the number

Comment: I copied the expression:

    regexp_substr("table_ot",'(\\d+)') 

It still doesn't let me run it.

Comment: can you describe which steps you tried, because I tried different values and it works

Comment: I simply open the field calculator and paste the above expression in the left window.